# repeat y axis scale along grid line of graph ( matplotlib)

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

I am new to matplotlib and I am trying to figure out if I can repeat the y axis scale 
values along the grid lines of the  line graph.

The graph has 2 axis,
x-axis has hourly values and y-axis has temperature values.

I need to show the graph for 48 hours, so it results in a long horizontal graph. when user scrolls through the graph horizontally he has x-axis scale available for reference but 
y axis scale is way towards left and is not visible.

I need a way to repeat the y-axis scale(temperature values) along all the graph. Is there any way to achieve this?

Is there any better solution to this problem, apart from repeating the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might take a look at the colorbar from [this example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/ellipse_collection.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.collections import EllipseCollection

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(15)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

XY = np.hstack((X.ravel()[:,np.newaxis], Y.ravel()[:,np.newaxis]))

ww = X/10.0
hh = Y/15.0
aa = X*9


ax = plt.subplot(1,1,1)

ec = EllipseCollection(
                        ww,
                        hh,
                        aa,
                        units='x',
                        offsets=XY,
                        transOffset=ax.transData)
ec.set_array((X+Y).ravel())
ax.add_collection(ec)
ax.autoscale_view()
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
cbar = plt.colorbar(ec)
cbar.set_label('X+Y')
plt.show()
```

A quick experiment shows me that you can pan/zoom the main window and the colorbar will stay constant.

Comment: I achieved the desired effect using jQuery clone using multiple div tags on client side.